# Fit scikit-learn algorithms with data stored in SFrame

Tags: numpy, scikit-learn, sframe

Is it possible to use data stored in Sframe to train e.g., a Random Forest, of scikit-learn implementation without converting the whole dataset to numpy?

Comment: No. I also think it is even impossible with the more equal SArray. sklearn/numpy is using a lot of assumptions about the data, so if your data-format just differ in one aspect it is not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

According by Turi-forum:

"If you use the most recent version of SFrame (which only became available via pip yesterday) you can use the [tonumpy function](https://dato.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.SFrame.tonumpy.html#graphlab.SFrame.to_numpy) to create an ndarray from an SFrame."

https://forum.turi.com/discussion/1642/

Comment: It is seems this solution needs the Graphlab create library, which is not longer available, I wonder how would be the solution to  use only SFrame open source.